# Reinstalling a MBR to a usb drive?

Tags: linux, usb, debian, mbr

Yesterday, by accident, I overwrote a bootable USB flash drive using dd. I did manage to recover **most** of the data on it (using TestDisk), including the partition containing the OS. The partition mounts correctly (along with another surviving partition), so it should be bootable. However, it refuses to do so. I suspect the MBR was overwrote; but even reinstalling the MBR via install-mbr it still refuses to boot. Is there any way I can resolve this, without having to do a full reinstall of Debian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I *really* should have looked around twice before posting this question; after following [this](https://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/installrecover-grub-from-linux-live-cd.html) tutorial I reinstalled GRUB onto the flash drive and it it booted up *almost* perfectly. After reconfiguring fstab to quit trying to mount the overwritten partition, via the emergency console, it booted up :) 
I hope this post helps fix many problems like this, so that unnecessary questions on this topic won't have to be posted.